# Ford Escort and Station Wagon Bumper Compatible?

Tags: ford, escort

I need to replace a bumper on a 1997 Ford Escort Station Wagon.  Would a regular Ford Escort bumper do the trick or are they not compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sites I've checked the fronts are the same the rears are different.

Answer (score 0):

The rear bumpers between the sedan and wagon are definitely not the same.  Unfortunately, the wagon bumper covers are hard to find and expensive.  If you've got a hole or crack in yours I would suggest you fix yours with fiberglass tape and bondo. Search the web and there are a number of good videos on how to do it.

(http://www.mechaniclifestyle.com/howtofixcrackedbumper.html)

Followed their instructions and mine has been good for over a year now.